# Merge unmanaged and managed dlls into single dll in DotNet

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, merge

I am developing mobile SDK in dotnet.I have a requirement of merging multiple dll's into single dll

Please find below the details
Merging dlls built on same .NET language
Merging Unmanaged and managed assemblies(.TLB,.LIB)
Merge dlls which refers to the unmanaged assemblies
One of the Dll is using OpenSSL library.

Please provide the information on tools for merging the dll's

Comment: Why do you need such a strange behaviour? .NET is not designed to create managed code, so you cannot combine managed and unmanaged code into one assembly. You can of course wrap your calls to managed functions into managed code, however you´ll need a reference to that unmanaged libraries.

Comment: Hi HimBromBeere,

We have multiple dlls like VC++,runtime dlls & Managed dlls. Currently i am embedding the unmanaged to managed dlls using Vitevic embedder & merging the multiple dll's into One DLL using ILMerge. But it is not working properly .The size of the merged dll is very less.

Please let me know is there a way to merge multiple dlls. We want to proved the client with single dll for deployment.

Comment: What do you think about BxILMerge ? It should help you.

Answer (score 3):

[BxILMerge](https://github.com/boxedapp/bxilmerge) is able to to merge unmanaged DLLs with managed DLL. Also, it cam marge sush files like images, videos, databases with managed DLL. This decision is based on  ILMerge+BoxedApp. I added a link to GitHub, there is an example of using this tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to merge all your managed code. However as far as I concerned you cannot put managed and unmanaged code together in one assembly.

Comment: Hi Chathuranga,

We have multiple dlls like VC++,runtime dlls & Managed dlls. Currently i am embedding the unmanaged to managed dlls using Vitevic embedder & merging the multiple dll's into One DLL using ILMerge. But it is not working properly .The size of the merged dll is very less.

Please let me know is there a way to merge multiple dlls. We want to proved the client with single dll for deployment.